# Display multiple records in form using a combo box and ApplyFilter

Tags: ms-access, combobox, macros

I am trying to display multiple records (with the same name in my field called PersOrgSubject) in my form by using a combo box. My row source is

`SELECT [TblBMcRecord].[ID], [TblBMcRecord].[PersOrgSubject] FROM TblBMcRecord;`

and my ApplyFilter is

[image: Combo52 Macro]

Comment: What is the issue - error messsage, wrong result, nothing happens?

Comment: It comes up with only one record. I want to see all records that match what I select in the combo box.

Comment: Apparently only one record matches the ID value. Must be filtering on wrong field. Edit question to show sample data as text table.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my ApplyFilter to show PersOrgSubject instead of ID
[ApplyFilter Macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMfq1.png)

Then in the Combo52 properties I changed Bound Column from 1 to 2
[Combo52 Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLvwA.png)

To note this was for a Multiple Items Form